# Embed .php webpage not showing

Tags: javascript

Hi i am using the code below to embed external site to my blog and it works for .html page but not .php

Please help me how to make .php showing on my blog

```
<head>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"\></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="docs">
</div>

<script>
$( "#docs" ).load( "http://www.aps.ai/tracking.php);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't simply include php script files from an external site.

Comment: The code you have there has syntax errors. There is no difference between including a URL with `.html` on the end and including one with `.php` on the end. The client sees no difference. Try looking for error messages in your browser's developer console.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<head>
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="docs">
</div>

<script>
$( "#docs" ).load("http://www.aps.ai/tracking.php");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

i think in .php you just need something like that

```
<body>
<div id="docs">
<?php include_once("http://www.aps.ai/tracking.php"); ?>
</div>
</body>
```